# print the non matching numbers by comparing two files in linux

Tags: unix, shell-script

For example i have two files

file1.txt with two coloumns seperated by :

1111:2222

3333:4444

5555:6666

7777:8888

file2.txt

1111:2222

3333:4444

5555:6666

i want to compare the second coloumn and the desired output should be 
7777:8888

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use `file1.txt` as the reference, i.e. give me everything in `file1.txt` that doesn't appear in `file2.txt` then you can use the [comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command:

```
comm -23 file1.txt file2.txt
```

Plus, if you would like to remove empty lines from the files / output you could use [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to remove them first, before comparing:

```
comm -23 <(sed '/^$/d' file1.txt) <(sed '/^$/d' file2.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "row", not "column"  (Rows run left to right, columns up to down).

The command you are looking for is

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: I am not looking for diff.. i want to  print the unique value among the two files